# I need to be able to display the value of cell in the if function

Tags: excel, if-statement

So stupid I am feeling dumb.  Tried but failing.  I want to subtract one time from another, if the resultant time is negative, then I want it to display zero.  Don't seem to have a problem with that.  I want the if function to display the value if it is greater than zero..... so it's kinda =if(a-b>0,?,0) where the ? is the value of the function...... lost

Comment: Don't worry about feeling stupid, we all have that feeling sometimes; but do take a breath and explain the whole problem. Give us the exact details of what you've got, what you want the output to be, and what you're stuck on right now. As it is now, it's hard to follow which bits you've got working, and what the actual question is.

Comment: It’s not pretty, but you could duplicate the computation: `=IF(a-b>0,a-b,0)`.

Comment: You can simplify the output with `=MAX(a-b,0)`. If the result is negative then 0 is returned. See [MAX function](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/max-function-f7bec1eb-9c66-489a-9166-51d2c9d19333).

Answer (score 0):

As @icktoofay said, one option is to repeat the formula: `=IF(a-b>0,a-b,0)`

Another option that'd be more compact for longer formulas is to use the `MAX` function instead of `IF`, like so: `=MAX(0, a-b)`. That way, anything less than 0 still gets displayed as 0, and anything greater than 0, as itself.